# undefined reference to `cuCtxGetCurrent` while getting CUDA context for OptiX

Tags: c++, cuda, linker, optix

I'm trying to learn how to implement OptiX into my C++ project. One of the first steps is to get the current CUDA context with `cuCtxGetCurrent(&some_CUcontext_variable)`, however I'm getting a compile time error saying that I've made an undefined reference to `cuCtxGetCurrent`.

Here's what I have:

- I'm following code from [this repo](https://github.com/ingowald/optix7course) to learn about OptiX and I'm on example 2 (where you get the CUDA context).
- In my code (`main.cpp`) I have included `cuda_runtime.h`, `device_launch_parameters.h`, `optix.h`, and `optix_stubs.h`, but I'm still getting the error at compile time.
- Interestingly, my IDE, JetBrains' CLion, is not showing any undefined reference errors/warnings inline. Errors only show up when I compile.
- In my `CMakeLists.txt`, I've used `find_package(CUDAToolkit REQUIRED)` to get CUDA. I then used `target_link_libraries{ ... CUDA::cudart}` to link in CUDA.

I believe this error is linker related, so I'm assume I'm missing something in my CMakeLists, but I don't know what. Please let me know how I can fix this issue!

Thank you in advanced for your help!

---

### Update #2: Solved

It's moments like this make make me pull my hair out: all I had to do with literally put `cuda` in my target link libraries. Not `-lcuda` or `CUDA::cuda`, just `cuda`. Somehow that linked in the drivers and it looks to be compiling now.

---

### [OLD, BUT KEPT FOR REFERENCE] Update #1: Here's my `CMakeLists.txt`.

Sorry for the lack of code in my original post. I was trying to avoid pasting large chunks of arbitrary code.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(My_Project_Name CUDA CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH
    "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake"
    ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})

find_package(CUDAToolkit REQUIRED)
find_package(OptiX REQUIRED VERSION 7.0)

add_executable(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    main.cpp [and other cpp and cu files])

# For project
set_target_properties(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    PROPERTIES
    CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON
)
target_compile_options(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    PRIVATE
    $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CUDA>:
    -arch=sm_61
    -gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52>
)
target_include_directories(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    PRIVATE
    include
    ${OptiX_INCLUDE}
)
target_link_libraries(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    PRIVATE
    CUDA::cudart
    CUDA::cublas
)
```

Comment: cuCtxGetCurrent is in the CUDA driver API. You need to link that

Comment: 1. Why are you setting properties and compile options for a target other than your executable? A target that doesn't seem to exists? 2. You have a "LABS" target, but that doesn't seem relevant.

Comment: Oops I did a very poor job shortening my CMakeLists lol. LABS is a separate set of files I use to test random bits of code. Using the same CMakeLists was just way easier for organization than creating a whole new project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @talonmies notes, CUDA has two (official) host-side APIs: The "CUDA Runtime API" and the "CUDA Driver API"; you can read about the difference between them [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/driver-vs-runtime-api.html#driver-vs-runtime-api).

You have mentioned files and CMake identifiers relating to the Runtime API: `cuda_runtime.h`, `CUDA::cudart`. But - "CUDA Contexts" are concepts of the Driver API, and `cuCtxGetCurrent()` etc. are driver API calls.

Specifically, an "undefined reference" is indeed a linker error. In your case, you need to link with the CUDA driver. As a library, on Linux systems, that's called `libcuda.so`. For that to happen, and for your executable named `ERPT_Render_Engine`, you need to add the command:

```
target_link_libraries(ERPT_Render_Engine cuda)
```

I'll also say that the `CMakeLists.txt` you listed above looks weird, because it defines dependencies for a target that doesn't exist - the project name; your relevant target is your executable.

Additionally - a CUDA context doesn't exist merely by virtue of you creating your process. You need to initialize the driver, create a context and make it current - or have something else do that for you (like a library) - before you can obtain the current context using  `cuCtxGetCurrent()`.

---

Finally, and in case you're interested, I am the author of the [C++ cuda-api-wrappers](https://github.com/eyalroz/cuda-api-wrappers) library, which covers (most of) the host-side functionality of both the driver and runtime APIs. Some example code:

```
cuda::initialize_driver();
(cuda::device::count() > 0) or die_("No CUDA devices on this system") {}
auto device_id =  cuda::device::default_device_id;
auto device = cuda::device::get(device_id);
auto context = cuda::context::create(device);
//etc. etc.
```

and when you using it within CMake (explained on the repository page), the dependencies are taken care of. But again - you really don't have to use this, it's just a convenience.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've updated my post with my CMakeList.txt, but I'll also take a look into including the CUDA driver API

Comment: After linking in the driver API, everything seems to be working now. Thanks for your help, and @talonmies' too.

Comment: @Microbob: See edit following your provision of a `CMakeLists.txt` file.

Answer (score 1):

Using plain old "cuda" may work, but it does create a "CUDA" target for you to use, so you should probably use that. I use something like the following.

```
target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME}
    PUBLIC CUDA::cudart
    PUBLIC CUDA::cuda_driver
)
```

[CMake Find CUDA Toolkit Documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindCUDAToolkit.html#cuda-toolkit-driver-lib)